# How to create a new file in unix?

Tags: unix

How do I create a new file in a different directory? If the file exists it should also create a new file.

I am using the command:

```
Touch workdirectory/filename.txt
```

Comment: the command is `touch` not Touch.

Comment: should be lower case t..

Comment: touch will not create a new file if it exists.  only update last access/modification times in that case.

Comment: Can you clarify what "If the file exists also it should create a new file" means? A new file with a composed name?

Comment: `install /dev/null empty_file`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `> workdirectory/filename.txt`

This would:

- truncate the file if it exists
- create if it doesn't exist

You can consider it equivalent to:

```
rm -f workdirectory/filename.txt; touch workdirectory/filename.txt
```

Comment: Meaning it will empty it in case already exists.

Answer (score 13):

The command is lowercase: `touch filename`.

Keep in mind that `touch` will only create a new file if it does not exist! Here's some docs for good measure: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch

If you always want an empty file, one way to do so would be to use:

```
echo "" > filename
```

Comment: The empty string will take a line. The correct answer should be `echo -n > filename`.